# What is happening in binary IO in C?

Tags: c, binary

I imagine this applies to a lot of other languages as well.

I have this code here, and I am wondering what is actually happening and how I can interpret what is written to the file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{
    //Initialize a variable and load it with input using scanf
    char write[100] = "Write this.";

    FILE *fp = fopen("./binFile.txt", "w+");
    fwrite(write, sizeof(write[0]), sizeof(write)/sizeof(write[0]), fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

and then when I open the text file I see this...

```
5772 6974 6520 7468 6973 2e00 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000
```

But I am having some trouble seeing exactly what is going on here. How does this text break down to binary?

Comment: You're opening the text file using a program which displays the hex codes of the characters in the file. `57` means `W`, `72` means `r`, etc.  If you open the file in a text editor you should see `Write this.` followed by however that editor displays null bytes

Comment: Seriously? you've never heard of ASCII?

Comment: Do you expect any kind of output?

Comment: @M.M I see so hex code 57 = 87 ASCII = W. Got it. Thanks. Why is it clustering like that (5772 6974..instead of 57 72 69 74)

Comment: The editor you are using thought that you'd like to see things clustered that way. You might be able to change this via the editor's configuration options

Comment: hmmm. ok thanks for the info, just curious what is happening behind the scenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the entire char array to the file, and the char array was initialized to 12 chars, followed by all zero values. That's why you see all the zeros after the string, perhaps that makes your system thinks it's a binary file. So use the following instead if you want to write a string:

```
fwrite(write, sizeof(write[0]), strlen(write), fp);
```